# Fazer variável enviada pelo POST perdurar

Tags: php, variáveis, post, biblioteca

Estou montando um sistema de biblioteca, em que na página anterior havia um select com todos os livros disponíveis em que o usuário poderia pegar emprestado, quando ele escolher o livro é enviado para a página "select.php" o id do livro, ande mostrará informações mais detalhadas, e um pequeno formulário para o empréstimo, em que enviará para a mesma página as informações via metodo POST, como faço para enviar o id escolhido na página anterior?

```
    if(!empty($_POST)){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `livros` WHERE id = '$id'");
    $dados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
    
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $id.'</br>'?></td>
        <td><?php echo $dados['livro']; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<form action="select.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="nome">
    <input type="text" name="matricula" placeholder="matricula">
    <input type="text" name="departamento" placeholder="departamento">
    <button type="submit">enviar</button>
</form>
    <?php
    if(!empty($_POST['matricula'])){
        $matricula = $_POST['matricula'];
        // $id = $dados['id'];
        $nome = $_POST['nome'];
        $departamento = $_POST['departamento'];
        // $livro = $dados['livro'];
        $data_emprestimo = date('Y/m/d');
        $data_devolucao = date('Y/m/d', strtotime('+ 14 days',strtotime($data_emprestimo)));
        $sql2 = "INSERT INTO `alugados` (`matricula`, `nome`, `departamento`, `livro`, `data-emprestimo`, `data-devolucao`) VALUES ('$matricula', '$nome', '$departamento', 'twstw', '$data_emprestimo', '$data_devolucao')";
        $insert = mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);
  }
//     ?>
 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Como assim fazer para enviar o id escolhido na página anterior? Explique com mais detalhes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você pode simplesmente colocar o id no href, e ao clicar no livro o usuário ser redirecionado para o select.php, com o parâmetro GET, ficando tipo: select.php?id=1;

Como você não postou o código da página anterior com o SELECT, não posso te dar um código detalhado, mas seria algo parecido com:

```
<a href="select.php?id=<?php echo $livro['id']; ?>">IMAGEM OU BOTÃO QUE QUER REDIRECIONAR AO CLICAR</a>
```

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score -2):

Você pode guardar o ID em uma sessão:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["idAnterior"] = $id;
```

```
<?php
session_start();
//RECUPERANDO NA PROXIMA PAGINA
echo $_SESSION["idAnterior"];
```